# Using what if parameters and using slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with entries as follows-

```
filenumber|metric1|metric2|metric3|overall score

1             90      80     70      ?
```

The requirement is to generate an overall score column. The user should be able to select which metric to consider while calculating the overall score and also to be able to assign weightages to each metric. For e.g in the above row,

If the user selects metric1 and metric2 and assigns a weightage of 0.7 and 0.3 respectively, the overall score should be

`0.7*90+0.3*80 = 87`

I have tried by using what if parameters for the user to set weightages. Also I have used unpivoted columns to select particular metrics but I am not able to combine the two requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unpivote is the right choice I think. but question is how you are passing/setting weightages?

Comment: I have used what if parameters so the user can select a weightage from 0 to 1 for each metric. I am using a DAX measure to calculate the overall score by using averagex and multiplying these weightages with the original metric values. For e.g Overall Score = AVERAGEX('Table',Table[metric1]*metric1Weightage value+Table[metric2]*metric2Weightage value+Table[metric3]*metric3Weightage value). The problem is the user should be able to select if he/she only wants to consider metric1 and metric2 to calculate overall score. So in that case AVERAGEX won't work as it will still divide by 3 instead of 2.

Comment: Do you have 3 what-if parameter for 3 metrics?

Comment: yes, one what-if parameter to set weightage for each metric

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below is the Measure, you should follow for your case-

```
overall score = 

VAR number_of_applied_Weightage = 
    IF(what_if_metric_1[metric_1 Value] > 0,1,0)+
    IF(what_if_metric_2[metric_2 Value] > 0,1,0)+
    IF(what_if_metric_3[metric_3 Value] > 0,1,0)

VAR total_score_current_row = 
    (MIN(what_if_parameter[metric1])*[metric_1 Value]) +
    (MIN(what_if_parameter[metric2])*[metric_2 Value]) +
    (MIN(what_if_parameter[metric3])*[metric_3 Value])

VAR average_score_current_row = 
    IF(
        number_of_applied_Weightage = 0,
        0,
        total_score_current_row/number_of_applied_Weightage
    )

RETURN average_score_current_row
```

It is working accurately here as shown in the below image-

[image]

Finally, to calculate the overall score for all together, you can create another measure as below-

```
average overll score = AVERAGEX(what_if_parameter,[overall score])
```